# clValid function to work for Big Data

Tags: r, bigdata, hierarchical-clustering

Package `clValid` reports validation measures for clustering results. The function returns an object of class `clValid`, which contains the clustering results in addition to the validation measures. The validation measures fall into three general categories: `internal`, `stability`, and `biological`.

```
 clValid(obj, nClust, clMethods="hierarchical", validation="stability", maxitems=600, 
         metric="euclidean", method="average", neighbSize=10, ...)
```

Any idea how to tweak the above function so that it works on big data (i.e., `maxitems >= 50000`)?

Answer (score 1):

I donot clearly understand your meaning of "tweak". Maybe you have to parallel this function. BTW, you can set the parameter `maxitems=nrow(obj)`, but it's really slow.

Update:
Here is a [paralled clValid](https://github.com/zhilongjia/clValid).

Comment: by "tweak" I meant overriding the default value, and yes it does get slow when you set `maxitems=nrow(obj)`

Comment: 'maxitems=nrow(obj)' will override the default value definitely.

Comment: I used maxitems = nrow(obj), but got an error: Error in if (nrow(mat) > maxitems { : argument is of length zero